# Calendar DATE field is not updated

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm working on some code that takes care of timezone differences (in this case, converting a date from UTC to EST/EDT) and I noticed that I'm getting the incorrect `DATE` field from the `Calendar` variable.

Here are the log excerpts from the timezone change:

```
UTC time: Fri Nov 15 00:28:44 EST 2013
America/New_York time: Thu Nov 14 19:28:44 EST 2013
```

The code is correctly updating the time to the 14th, based on what shows up with `Calendar.getTime()`, but when I call `Calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)`, I'm still getting 15 as the date.

Why are the fields not updating when the time itself is?

---

**Code excerpt:**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());

TimeZone fromTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
TimeZone toTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");

jlog.info(fromTz.getID() + " time: " + cal.getTime().toString());

cal.setTimeZone(fromTz);
// Finds the difference between the two timezones based on their offset from UTC (in the case of the system timezone changing in the future).
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
int timeDifference = toTz.getOffset(currentTime) - fromTz.getOffset(currentTime);

cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeDifference);

if (dst) { // Logic for determining whether or not the extra hour for DST is needed.
  cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, fromTz.getDSTSavings());
}

jlog.info(toTz.getID() + " time: " + cal.getTime().toString());

jlog.info(cal.getTime().toString() + " - " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

---

**Output for the above code:**

```
UTC time: Fri Nov 15 00:28:44 EST 2013
America/New_York time: Thu Nov 14 19:28:44 EST 2013
Thu Nov 14 19:28:44 EST 2013 - 15
```

---

**NOTE:** Please don't suggest that I use Joda-time.  I'm just looking for an answer to this question as is.

If it's not solvable because Calendar/Date are terrible packages, that's fine - I'll just parse the date myself to get the correct values.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown us enough code to know what's going on, but your output is very easy to explain: you're calling `Date.toString()` which *always* formats the instant in time using the system local time zone. The time zone in the `Calendar` object is irrelevant.

So it looks like your `Calendar` may be in UTC for example, in which case the day *is* 15.

Note that the first line of your log is clearly nonsense:

```
UTC time: Fri Nov 15 00:28:44 EST 2013
```

It's either UTC or it's EST. It can't be both.

It's not clear where your data comes from or exactly how you're dealing with it, but if you're *manually* adjusting the date/time by adding or subtracting parts, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. It's very important to understand that a `java.util.Date` doesn't have any notion of a time zone as part of its data - it's *just* an instant in time.

To *format* a `Date` in a particular time zone, you'd usually use a `SimpleDateFormat` and specify the time zone on that. For example:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("The time in New York is " + format.format(new Date()));
```

EDIT: Now that we've seen your code, you should definitely *not* do things that way. You're adjusting the point in time, which isn't what you want - you only want to change your *view* on the same point in time, which can be achieved using `Calendar.setTimeZone` to change what's returned by `Calendar.get`, and using `DateFormat.setTimeZone` to change which time zone is used for parsing/formatting text.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification.  The code is being tested in an environment that is in America/New_York time, but I've set the `TimeZone` to UTC to see what it will look like when it is deployed to an environment in UTC time.  That's why the `Date.toString()` output lists EST but the conversion still occurs.


I'll update the question with some more information.

Comment: @LeMazing: What conversion? You haven't told us details of what you're trying to do, or shown us the code you're using to do it.

Comment: Added the code and more details.  I hadn't realized `DateFormat` would take care of timezones all on its own, otherwise I would have just used that.  But I tried it and it does work, so I'll scrap the current code.  Thanks for your help.  I'm still curious as to why `Calendar.getTime()` and `Calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)` are conflicting, but it's irrelevant when `DateFormat.format()` works so well.

Comment: @LeMazing: It's because `Calendar.get(Calendar.DATE())` is using the time zone of the calendar, whereas `Calendar.getTime()` returns an *instant in time*, which is then being *formatted* with your local time zone. That's all it is. You should *absolutely* not use your current code, adjusting for a time zone manually. You're basically changing the underlying instant in time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could do it with something like this -

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
        Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // <-- Set the timezone on the
                                                    // DateFormat
/* Your input date/time */
c.setTime(new GregorianCalendar(2013, 10, 15, 0, 28, 44).getTime());

System.out.println(formatter.format(c.getTime()));
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

The output of this code is

```
Fri Nov 15 05:28:44 UTC 2013
Fri Nov 15 00:28:44 EST 2013
```

Comment: Hi Elliott Frisch - Please make two changes to your answer: (1) Replace `YYYY` with `yyyy` (2) Please use `Locale.ENGLISH` with `SimpleDateFormat` e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) explains why it is important.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Edited. Solid advice. 7 year old answer though.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2013, 11, 15), LocalTime.of(0, 28, 44),
                ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-11-14T19:28:44-05:00[America/New_York]
Thu Nov 14 19:28:44 EST 2013
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/yNFh4y)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>